# How can I integrate Apache Solr search with my Java webapp?

Tags: java, json, jsp, tomcat, solr

I deployed **Solr**.war on **Tomcat** server. I run it successfully and also I am getting total response in json format. I want search with specific keyword, how can I pass that word to **Solr** server?

My exact requirement is when I enter search word in search box in jsp (like in google), I want retrieve results using **Solr** in that page.

How can integrate **Solr** search  with my web application?

Comment: what did you achieve so far? what did you try with Solr?

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902833/how-to-integrate-solr-with-web-application?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My exact requirement is when I enter search word in search box in jsp (like in google), I want retrieve results using Solr in that page.

For this you need to construct a SolrQuery object something like this

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery( /* your query goes here */);
QueryResponse response = server.query( query );
```

And then parse the response. Hope this will help you :)

Comment: thanks for replay to all ,i understand how to use it. ifollwed this link http://moderntone.blogspot.in/2013/02/tutorial-on-solrj.html